# how many war can we deploy onto tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

how many war can we deploy onto tomcat?

is there any limitations???

Comment: Until you've signed the peace treaty.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan +1 for the peace treaty mention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. you can only launch so many war as you have system resources such as disk and memory for.

Comment: hmm...i know your point.

i just wonder...if the resource is good enough(hardware).....
coz the war might affect the other wars..
so if too many wars have been deploy to the same tomcat..there might be make all the application get slow down...

Comment: Since instances of a single web-app can share a lot of overlapped memory (more pages of memory will be able to be shared) running more web-apps at the same time is going to use more memory. So running 10 different web-apps one time each is going to use more memory than 10 instances of a single web-app.